# Repeat a value over some rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of values and I have to display the mother value of the `CHILDVALUE` in the following way. The `MOTHERVALUE` should be same as `CHILDVALUE` at `RNO = 1` ,  Otherwise the `MOTHERVALUE` is repeated for subsequent rows until a new sequence beginning from RNO = 1 is encountered. Below is what I wish to achieve

```
RNO ChildValue  MotherValue SKIPNO  CREATEDDATE
1   345dg       345dg       4   19/9/2018 2:49
2   342sds      345dg       4   19/9/2018 11:53
.
.
.               
19  343dfd      345dg       4   6/11/2018 12:40
20  234dfs      345dg       4   6/11/2018 14:56
1   545ert      545ert      4   6/11/2018 15:17
2   543tye      545ert      4   7/11/2018 11:29
.
.
.               
9   345cxv      545ert      4   16/11/2018 14:16
1   563mnj      563mnj      5   19/11/2018 2:12
```

The row numbers are dynamically produced according to the `SKIPNO` (not distinct) and `CREATEDDATE`. But I have a problem in displaying the correct `MOTHERVALUE` for some of the rows

I have tried the below query which best captures at least 50% of the requirement.

```
 select RNO
        , CHILDVALUE 
       , case RNO when 1 then CHILDVALUE 
           else lag(MOTHERVALUE) over (order by SKIPNO, CreatedDate ASC) end as MOTHERVALUE
       , SKIPNO, CreatedDate 
from( SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.SKIPNO
              ORDER BY A.SKIPNO,  A.CreatedDate ASC) RNO
          , A.* 
      from  (select distinct CHILDVALUE
                    , CHILDVALUE as MOTHERVALUE
                    , SKIPNO
                    , CreatedDate 
              from values ) A
          )
      )
```

This query partially gives the expected output but is still far from the actual result as it shows the correct `MOTHERVALUE only for the first two rows. The query does not help me to show the correct`MOTHERVALUE` for more than second row.

Here is my table:

```
   CREATE TABLE VALUES (
      CHILDVALUE VARCHAR2(36), 
      SKIPNO VARCHAR2(36), 
      CREATEDDATE DATE)
```

Pls help.

Comment: Can you please share the create table scripts and insert scripts

Comment: Please do NOT use these small comments for data. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53368572/edit) the question and format that text using this icon `{}`  in the toolbar.

Comment: CREATE TABLE VALUES (CHILDVALUE VARCHAR2(36), SKIPNO VARCHAR2(36), CREATEDDATE DATE)

Comment: @tenter - for future reference, please **edit your question** to improve your question. Code and data is too hard to read in comments, due to small text size and lack of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

*N.B. I am assuming that your sample data had incorrect skipnos for the second and third groups. My answer uses updated values in its sample data.*

You can use the `first_value` analytic function, rather than `lag` to achieve your aim, e.g.:

```
WITH vals AS (SELECT '345dg' childvalue, 4 skipno, to_date('19/09/2018 02:49', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT '342sds' childvalue, 4 skipno, to_date('19/09/2018 11:53', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT '343dfd' childvalue, 4 skipno, to_date('06/11/2018 12:40', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT '234dfs' childvalue, 4 skipno, to_date('06/11/2018 14:56', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT '545ert' childvalue, 5 skipno, to_date('06/11/2018 15:17', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT '543tye' childvalue, 5 skipno, to_date('07/11/2018 11:29', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT '345cxv' childvalue, 5 skipno, to_date('16/11/2018 14:16', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT '563mnj' childvalue, 6 skipno, to_date('19/11/2018 02:12', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') createddate FROM dual)
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY skipno ORDER BY createddate) rno,
       childvalue,
       first_value(childvalue) OVER (PARTITION BY skipno ORDER BY createddate) mothervlue,
       skipno,
       createddate
FROM   vals;

       RNO CHILDVALUE MOTHERVLUE     SKIPNO CREATEDDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1 345dg      345dg               4 19/09/2018
         2 342sds     345dg               4 19/09/2018
         3 343dfd     345dg               4 06/11/2018
         4 234dfs     345dg               4 06/11/2018
         1 545ert     545ert              5 06/11/2018
         2 543tye     545ert              5 07/11/2018
         3 345cxv     545ert              5 16/11/2018
         1 563mnj     563mnj              6 19/11/2018
```